# How to load/get all classes in a package using OSGi?

Tags: java, osgi

I'd like to load all classes in a package, does anyone know how to do this without any third party library?

For example,
in package com.example.test, there're classes: A.java, B.java, C.java, D.java, and E.java, etc.

Is there a way to load all classes in com.example.test upon OSGi activation?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over *entries* with `Bundle.findEntries()`. Remember that a java class `com.example.A` has a path `com/example/A.class`.

This works most of the time except for *fragments* and the *bundle classpath*. The sanity of both ideas can be doubted but the sad story is that they are used. Fragments are other bundles that get class loader linked into a host bundle. You will, therefore, have to find out the fragments and traverse those as well.

The Bundle-ClasPath is a header. It lists a set of resources in the bundle that should be placed on the bundle's classpath. You have to traverse them as well.

If you can control the bundle you want to traverse yourself, then do not use fragments and do not use the Bundle-ClassPath. Which in general is a good idea anyway, these concepts are almost never crucial.